# validacion de busqueda en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

tengo un buscador en laravel para equipos por su ip y por su codigo de barra para eso cree dos scopes

```
     public function scopeBuscarip($query, $ip)
  {
    if (trim($ip) != '') {
      $query = $query->where('ip', $ip);
    }
  }

  public function scopeBuscarcod($query, $ip)
  {
    if (trim($ip) != '') {
      $query = $query->where('cod_barra', $ip);
    }
  }
```

asi funciona bien pero cuando no tengo productos registrados me crea un bucle de redirecionbamientos ese es mi problema alguien me puede ayudar con esta validacion

este es mi codigo en el controlador

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
      $equipos = Equipo::buscarip($request->ip)->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->paginate(10);

       if (count($equipos) == null) {
        $equipos = Equipo::buscarcod($request->ip)->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->paginate(10);
        if (count($equipos) == null) {
          flash('No existe equipo registrado con la IP o el Codigo de Barra: ' . $request->ip , 'danger');
          return redirect()->route('equipos.index');
        }else{
            return view('equipos.list')->with('equipos', $equipos);
        }
      }else{
        return view('equipos.list')->with('equipos', $equipos);
      }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué debería ocurrir cuando no hay productos registrados?

Comment: un mensaje de alerta que no existe equipos registrados

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema principal es que cuando no hay resultados, rediriges al mismo método, por lo cual se genera una redirección infinita.

La solución probablemente sea (depende de como hayas diseñado tu aplicación) mostrar la misma vista del listado de equipos junto con el "flash" emergente que informe que no hay equipos registrados.

Adicional a tu problema principal, veo otras mejoras posibles a tu código, como eliminar responsabilidades que no le corresponden a los Scopes y reducir el código redundante en el controlador, esto sin ir muy lejos y no hablar de otras capas para quitarle responsabilidades al controlador:

1. No debería ser responsabilidad de los scopes tener que "limpiar" los datos de entrada, eso es responsabilidad del request o de un servicio, en el peor de los casos, en el controlador:

   ```
   public function scopeBuscarip($query, $ip)
   {
       $query = $query->where('ip', $ip);
   }

   public function scopeBuscarcod($query, $ip)
   {
       $query = $query->where('cod_barra', $ip);
   }
   ```
2. Aparte del problema principal de redireccionamiento infinito, puedes mejorar la comprobación de los arreglos vacíos y hacer una pequeña reescritura del código para que se pueda entender y mantener más fácilmente:

   ```
   public function index(Request $request)
   {
       $equipos = [];

       $equipos = Equipo::buscarip($request->ip)->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->paginate(10);

       $equipos = empty($equipos) ? Equipo::buscarcod($request->ip)->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->paginate(10) : $equipos;

       if (empty($equipos)) {
           flash('No existe equipo registrado con la IP o el Codigo de Barra: ' . $request->ip , 'danger');
       }

       return view('equipos.list')->with('equipos', $equipos);
   }
   ```

El código se lee un poco extraño, especialmente porque compruebas dos veces la propiedad ip del request con dos campos distintos de la base de datos, lo cual aparentemente no sería muy lógico, pero ya depende de los requisitos y el diseño de tu aplicación.